# ember cli dont compile with daterangepicker

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I install ember-cli-daterangepicker. I did error server and this had working good, but I get error now. I install anything.

I do `ember server` and get it

```
File: ember-cli-daterangepicker/components/date-range-picker.js The
Broccoli Plugin: [broccoli-persistent-filter:Babel] failed with:
Error: incorrect header check
 at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17)


The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
 at Babel.Plugin (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
 at Babel.Filter [as constructor] (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\broccoli-persistent-filter\index.js:62:10)
 at new Babel (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\broccoli-babel-transpiler\index.js:35:10)
 at EmberApp._addonTree (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:913:29)
 at EmberApp._processedVendorTree (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:947:20)
 at EmberApp._processedExternalTree (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:978:21)
 at EmberApp.appAndDependencies (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1087:30)
 at EmberApp.javascript (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1217:34)
 at EmberApp.toArray (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1646:10)
 at EmberApp.toTree (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1668:30)
 at module.exports (F:\Projects\tomaq\ember-cli-build.js:43:14)
 at CoreObject.setupBroccoliBuilder (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:72:19)
 at CoreObject.init (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:52:10)
 at CoreObject.superWrapper [as init] (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\core-object\lib\assign-properties.js:32:18)
 at CoreObject.Class (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:32:33)
 at CoreObject.run (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:15:19)
 at F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\commands\serve.js:76:24
 at tryCatch (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:539:12)
 at invokeCallback (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:554:13)
 at publish (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:522:7)
 at flush (F:\Projects\tomaq\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2414:5)
 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

How fix it problem?

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "tomaq",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for tomaq goes here",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.4.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.10.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
    "ember-cli-daterangepicker": "0.6.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-g-maps": "0.5.14",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.10",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.3",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.1",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-lazy-load": "0.3.0",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "3.5.0",
    "ember-cli-pagination": "3.0.2",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.10.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-moment": "^7.3.1",
    "ember-perfectscroll": "0.1.15",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-rx-shim": "0.1.4",
    "ember-scrollable": "0.4.9",
    "ember-simple-pagination": "1.0.1",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.3.0",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^1.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-compass": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-ember-handlebars": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^0.6.5",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.10"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "ember-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ember-i18n": "^5.0.1",
    "ember-validations": "2.0.0-alpha.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's problem with [cache](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/7396) in ember. It was related to running two ember-cli processes in parallel. Change `BROCCOLI_PERSISTENT_FILTER_CACHE_ROOT` path

```
BROCCOLI_PERSISTENT_FILTER_CACHE_ROOT=./dist-build-cache ember-cli build -prod
```

Answer (score 0):

When I see `zlib` errors, I often need to either restart my `ember` server or clear my `node_modules` folder and re-install packages.  Does that resolve things for you?